# Is there any way auto generate graphql schema from protobuf?

Tags: java, spring-boot, graphql, protocol-buffers

I am developing springboot with GraphQL. Since the data structure is already declared within Protobuf, I tried to use it. This is example of my code.

```
@Service
public class Query implements GraphQLQueryResolver {

    public MyProto getMyProto() {
       /**/
    }

}
```

I want make code like upper structure. To to this, I divided job into 2 sections.

- 1. Since ".proto file" can be converted to java class, I will use this class as return type.

And The second section is a main matter.

- 2. Also Schema is required. At first, I tried to code schema with my hand. But, the real size of proto is about 1000 lines. So, I want to know Is there any way to convert ".proto file" to ".graphqls file".

Answer (score 0):

There is a way. I am using the a protoc plugin for that purpose: [go-proto-gql](https://github.com/danielvladco/go-proto-gql)

It is fairly simple to be used, for example:

```
protoc --gql_out=paths=source_relative:. -I=. ./*.proto
```

Hope this is working for you as well.